# how to run a query in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert into the table one data by default when the user starts the program.  I need to insert data into the table after it is created.

```
class AddressBookDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AddressBook.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   // constructor
   public AddressBookDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   // creates the contacts table when the database is created
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // SQL for creating the contacts table
      final String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
         "CREATE TABLE " + Contact.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
         Contact._ID + " integer primary key, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_STREET + " TEXT, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_CITY + " TEXT, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_STATE + " TEXT, " +
         Contact.COLUMN_ZIP + " TEXT);";

      final String Beregero =
              "INSERT INTO " + Contact.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                      Contact._ID + " 3, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_NAME + " Patrice Beregeron, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_PHONE + " 978-555-1212, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL + " pBeregero@BostonBruins.com, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_STREET + " 1 causeway street, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_CITY + " Boston, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_STATE + " Mass, " +
                      Contact.COLUMN_ZIP + " 01236);";

      db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); // create the contacts table
      db.execSQL(Beregero);
   }

   // normally defines how to upgrade the database when the schema changes
   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
      int newVersion) { }
}
```

I found the following error when I try to execute the second query. any help on how I can create the single row. many thanks.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
                                                                        Process: com.deitel.addressbook, PID: 13285
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:142)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "3": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(_id 3, name Patrice Beregeron, phone 978-555-1212, email pBeregero@BostonBruins.com, street 1 causeway street, city Boston, state Mass, zip 01236);
                                                                        #################################################################
                                                                        Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                        Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                            (near "3": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(_id 3, name Patrice Beregeron, phone 978-555-1212, email pBeregero@BostonBruins.com, street 1 causeway street, city Boston, state Mass, zip 01236);)
                                                                        #################################################################
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1829)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1760)
                                                                            at com.deitel.addressbook.data.AddressBookDatabaseHelper.onCreate(AddressBookDatabaseHelper.java:47)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                            at com.deitel.addressbook.data.AddressBookContentProvider.query(AddressBookContentProvider.java:75)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1058)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:245)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:29)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:128)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                ... 3 more
```

Comment: By the way, you really should have a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  You override the `onCreate()` method, and the `onUpgrade()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have `INSERT INTO contacts(_id 3,.....` and also similar inclusions of the data to be inserted within the list of columns into which the data is to be inserted. The data itself should follow `VALUES(`, each value should separated from the next by a comma and strings should be enclosed in quotes. The last value should be followed by the closing parenthesis.

So instead of :-

```
INSERT INTO contacts(_id 3, name Patrice Beregeron, phone 978-555-1212, email pBeregero@BostonBruins.com, street 1 causeway street, city Boston, state Mass, zip 01236);
```

You should have :-

```
INSERT INTO contacts(_id,name,phone,email,street,city,state,zip)  VALUES(3,'Patrice Beregeron','978-555-1212','pBeregero@BostonBruins.com',`1 causeway street','Boston','Mass','01236');
```

i.e. the INSERT statement has the following syntax :-

[image]

[SQL As Understood By SQLite- INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

P.S. the  'onCreate' method will only be run if the database doesn't exist. So until you fix all the statements within the `onCreate` method. You will need to delete the database in order to have the code rerun. You can either delete the App's data or uninstall the App to achieve this.

### Additonal

You could alternatively utilise the `insert` convenience method, which builds the SQL on your behalf. The entire `onCreate` method could be :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL for creating the contacts table
    final String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + Contact.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        Contact._ID + " integer primary key, " +
        Contact.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
        Contact.COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
        Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
     Contact.COLUMN_STREET + " TEXT, " +
     Contact.COLUMN_CITY + " TEXT, " +
     Contact.COLUMN_STATE + " TEXT, " +
     Contact.COLUMN_ZIP + " TEXT);";
     db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); // create the contacts table

     ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     cv.put(Contact._ID,3);
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_NAME,"Patrice Beregeron");
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_PHONE,"978-555-1212");
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL,"pBeregero@BostonBruins.com");
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_STREET,"1 causeway street");
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_CITY,"Boston");
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_STATE,"Mass");
     cv.put(Contact.COLUMN_ZIP,"01236");
     db.insert(Contact.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
}
```